# how to push item in array in document.ready and onsucess of button click using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var SelectedAnswer;
var qestionarray = [];
var ansewrarray = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  qestionarray.push(@question.Id) 
  SelectedAnswer = ($(':radio[name="Dummy"]:checked').val());

  $(':radio[name="Dummy"]').on('click', function() {
    SelectedAnswer = ($(':radio[name="Dummy"]:checked').val());
  });


  $("#nextbtn").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "/User/GetNextQuestion",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        Id: @question.Id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#loadquestion").html(data);
        qestionarray.push(@question.Id);/* not getting id of first question while loaded, else other ids I am getting*/
        ansewrarray.push(SelectedAnswer);
        if ($("#finish").click(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/User/checkResult",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              ans: ansewrarray,
              quest: qestionarray
            },
            success: function(data) {}

          });

        }));

      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error")

      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hello I need to add items on success of next button click..its working fine but the first items loaded on document.ready are not coming...

please need help....
Hello I need to add items on success of next button click..its working fine but the first items loaded on document.ready are not coming...

please need help....

Comment: where your document.ready function closed?

Comment: yah I have closed it..no issue for that

Comment: is this `@question.Id` rails?

Comment: Have you try this `qestionarray.push("@question.Id");`? What's @question.Id?

Comment: Yes its working all. I just need help for appending @question.Id in the push

Comment: is working as @model.id as I have stored it in tempdata

Comment: *qestionarray.push(@question.Id);/* not getting id of first question while loaded, else other ids I am getting*/* ?  What is `@question`???